# set visible on others selectors without parent and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can use children() and parent() but what if inputs not are children and parent?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    <select style="display: none"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <select style="display: none"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <input type="text" style="display: none">
</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    <select style="display: none"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <select style="display: none"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <input type="text" style="display: none">
</td></tr><tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    <select style="display: none"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <select style="display: none"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <input type="text" style="display: none">
</td></tr><tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    <select style="display: none"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <select style="display: none"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <input type="text" style="display: none">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

if i check checkbox with class check then 2 select and input should be visible. How can i make with jQuery?

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/ykyNq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your situation you can use a few different selectors to find siblings.  In this case you can use `siblings()`

```
$('.check').click(function(){    
    $(this).siblings("select, input").toggle() 
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykyNq/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select all it's siblings(elements at the same level under the same parent)

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykyNq/4/